# Ways of Creating List from Dask dataframe column

Tags: python, dask, dask-dataframe

I want to create a list/set from Dask Dataframe column. Basically, i want to use this list to filter rows in another dataframe by matching values with a column in this dataframe. I have tried using `list(df[column])`  and `set(df[column])` but it takes lot of time and ends up giving error regarding creating cluster or sometimes it restarts kernel when memory limit is reached.

Can i use `dask.bag` or Multiprocessing to create a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you try to convert a column to a list or set with the regular `list/set` Python will load that into memory, that's why you get a memory limit issue.

I believe that by using `dask.bag` you might solve that issue since `dask.bag` will lazy load your data, although I'm not sure if the `df[column]` won't have to be read first. Also, be aware that turning that column into a bag will take a while depending on how big the data is.

Using a `dask.bag` allows you to run map, filter and aggregate so it seems it could be a good solution for your problem.

You can try to run this to see if it filters the list/bag as you expect.

```py
import dask.bag as db

bag = db.from_sequence(df[column], npartitions=5) 

bag.filter(lamdba list_element: list_element == "filtered row")
```

Since this is just an example, you will need to change the `npartitions` and the lambda expression to fit your needs.

Let me know if this helps

Comment: Hey @FabioRosado, i tried creating bag from  `df[column]` but it look almost 2  minutes in creating a bag. My Dataframe has around 10 million rows. may be this is why it look quite a time.

Comment: Got to be honest I was afraid of that,  my initial intuition told me that by passing the dataframe to a bag, dask will have to read each element first, even if doing it in a lazy way it will take n time to read.

I will try to see if I can come up with a better way to do this and edit my reply if I can think of something

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon this today, and solved it with a simple list comprehension:

```
column = [c for c in df.column]
```

Still much slower than on a pandas frame though.